# HTML/CSS/JS Syntax Highlighting in Eclipse

Tags: python, html, eclipse, syntax, cheetah

Hello How can I enable syntax highlighting for HTML/CSS/JS in Eclipse I am mainly developing in python using the PyDev package but right now I am creating Cheetah templates and they are very hard to read unhighlighted.

Any plugin/package suggestions related to Cheetah or just highlighting any file as html would be greatly appreciated.

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I somehow trick Eclipse into treating .tmpl files as if they were .html?

It's not a trick.

Under Windows -> Preferences, General -> Editors -> File Associations, you can associate *.tmpl files with your HTML editor.

Comment: Thank you what is the editor for HTML in eclipse I have "Schema html editor" but it does not work I feel like this is on the right path but im still missing some piece or plugin

Comment: @user564559: The standard HTML editor for Eclipse is the Eclipse Web Developer Tools.  These tools are a part of the Eclipse Web Tools Platform.  It shows up in my File Associations list as HTML Editor.

Comment: Ok I got that doesnt seem to want to work with .tmpl but at least my .css files are now syntax highlighted thanks

Comment: Uh .. I'm confused. Did someone edit the original question? There's no mention of .tmpl files in it.

Comment: If you're trying to determine how to enable syntax highlighting for HTML, go to "Help" > "Install New Software" Choose to work with the site "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo", Expand "Web, XML and Java EE development", Check "Web Page Editor" and click Next to continue with the install. (thanks @Andrew) I also installed "JavaScript Development Tools" in a very similar fashion, and things seem to be working well.